# AST matcher for C++ #include

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree

Context:
I need to write a codegen to add missing dependencies in C++ for multiple files by adding the missing #include "someheader.h". I'm thinking to use AST but I'm new to AST.

Therefore, I'm trying to make it straightforward by creating a matcher to match the #include string and add the new #include line below it. Since all my target files have their own header include, this guarantees at least one #include keyword in the cpp file.

Is the above approach feasible? If so, which matcher should I use?
After adding the #include, can I re-use the matcher to find a function declaration and modify its content?

Or if there are better ways to achieve the same result without using AST?

Comment: There's really no need to do any detailed parsing except comments and `#include` directives. Just read line by line, if it's a comment or part of a block-comment, just skip it. If it's an `#include` just skip it. And when you find a line that is not a comment, part of a block-comment, or `#include` directive, add your own `#include` together with an empty line.

Comment: But before doing all that, I recommend to check if there really *is* a header file to include, otherwise just skip the file.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about reading line by line? Do you mean reading it through AST or some other method?

Comment: No just read normal lines with `std::getline`. Skip all leading spaces. Do you have a `//` then just skip the line and go to the next. If the line is an `#include*`, again just skip the line and go to the next line. If it's neither a comment, nor an `#include`, you add your own `#include` above the current line.

Comment: `#include` is the preprocessor directive to replace the line with the content of the target file, so it works long before AST parsing kick in